# Command not creating project of reactjs

Tags: reactjs

app not creating

F:\react>create-react-app axixa
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Google the error message, you'll find dozens of posts answering your question. Install node and add it as an environment variable.

Comment: @Jayce444 i already intalled node

Comment: after installing node, you need to restart your computer

Answer (score 0):

use npx ensure that your node and npm is working

```
npx create-react-app my-app
cd my-app
npm start
```

follow their documentation https://create-react-app.dev/docs/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

This should solve it

`npx create-react-app your-react-app`